# Django : Create a model on creating a user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

There is a Django model `Item` and an AbstarctUser `itemOwner`. Upon creating an `itemOwner`, I need to create its corresponding `item`. The  views and models of `Item` and `ItemOwner` are as shown below:

```
class ItemOwner(AbstractUser):
    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='owner',null=True)

class ItemOwnerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ItemOwner.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemOwnerSerializer

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, verbose_name='name')

class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```

`Item` need to be created with the values that have been passed as arguments for creating `ItemOwner`. I know that a model can be created with `modelname.save("parameters")`. But here the parameters are accessed from the request and i don't know from where i should take the request instance using a ViewSet. What i am exactly looking for is a methode that will be called only when an `ItemOwner` is created, and this methode should have a `request` instance to retrieve the arguments so that i can create the `Item` model with it . How can i do it?

Comment: Is that a typo in `ItemOwnerViewSet` queryset ? Why you wanted to access request after ItemOwner created ? I guess Item has only one field which is ` `name` and correct me if I'm wrong owner_name is equal to Item.name right ? So you can create a post_signal for ItemOwner and create `Item` ?

Comment: owner_name is not item name. both are different. and i am new to django and don't know exactly how post_signal and all works. plz show me the code

Comment: typo is cleared now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `post_signal` to `ItemOwner` model. And after the object created you can easily create Item object.

**models.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

--- Your Models here ---

# method for updating
@receiver(post_save, sender=ItemOwner)
def create_item(sender, instance, **kwargs):
     item_obj = Item.objects.get_or_create(name=instance.owner_name)
     instance.item = item_obj
     instance.save()
```

Update:

```
class ItemOwnerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = ItemOwner.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ItemOwnerSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(item=Item.objects.get_or_create(name=self.request.data.get('name'))
```

Comment: name=instance.owner_name,. this is wrong. name is another field that will be passed in the request.

Comment: yeah I don't have the clear picture of your request though. Please elaborate your question. In that case this signal thing is invalid.

Comment: Tell how you added that extra field in your request. May be show your full serializer will help

Comment: as a key value field in request body

Comment: @HariKrishnan I updated the answer but I have no idea that will work. Try and let me know